# Rowfilter with multiple texboxes

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid, rowfilter

I would like to use two different textboxes to filter information from a database to display baseball players average score. Example selecting 0,3 to 0,4, should display players with scores between these number.

Whats not working is the following code:

```
// Search for player, working
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            view.RowFilter = "LastName like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
            if (textBox1.Text == "") view.RowFilter = string.Empty;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mattias\Dropbox\C#\Database\Baseball.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
            connection.Open();
            datatable.Load(new SqlCommand("select * from players", connection).ExecuteReader());
            dataGridView1.DataSource = view = datatable.DefaultView;
            connection.Close();
        }
// This button is not working
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal minimum = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text);
            decimal maximum = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox3.Text);
// Should display players with different scores
            view.RowFilter = String.Format("BattingAverage >= {0} AND BattingAverage <= {1}"
                , minimum, maximum);

            if (textBox2.Text == "") view.RowFilter = string.Empty;
            if (textBox3.Text == "") view.RowFilter = string.Empty;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RowFilter` does not support the `BETWEEN` operator. It also doesn't support complete sql queries like yours. However, you can specify the `WHERE`-clause there to filter the rows of the view:

```
view.RowFilter = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat,
                 "BattingAverage >= {0} AND BattingAverage <= {1}", minimum, maximum);
```

I've used `InvariantCulture.NumberFormat` in `String.Format` to ensure the english format(dots as decimal separator) in `RowFilter` which is required.

Note that you also have wrapped the values with apostrophes which is not allowed on numbers and that you're using `textBox2.Text` as input for your minimum **and** maximum value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately the code doesn't work. I fixed the name for textBox2.Text(maximum) and the new code gives med the following error: Syntax error in the expression

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what? What is the corrected code that throws an syntax error? What numbers does the user enter, with decimal places?

Comment: The code that throws the syntax error is: view.RowFilter = string.Format("BattingAverage >= {0} AND BattingAverage <= {1}" ,minimum, maximum; The numbers that are entered is 0,3 and 0,4 in the two different textboxes. 0,3 and 0,4 should filter players within these ranges.

Comment: @user1982973: Edited my answer. Try to use `String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat ...` since `RowFilter` needs the english format of decimal places(dots instead of commas).

Comment: Sorry, still the same error message. I tried using view.RowFilter = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat("BattingAverage... But now is says: Non-invocable member 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo.NumberFormat'..

Comment: @user1982973: It's not understandable what you have tried from the comments. Please edit your question and add my approach with a comment what exception you get. Then we might be able to find the reason. (it works for me in any culture)

Comment: Thank you for your comment @TimSchmelter! It now works!! view.RowFilter = String.Format(Culture.Info.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat,("BattingAverage >= {0} AND BattingAverage <= {1}"), minimum, maximum);

Comment: @user1982973: Sorry, i've missed your last comment about your updated question somehow. I'm glad to hear that it works now. Although that seems to be the code that i've already provided in my answer. Remember to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It now works by adding CultureInfo.
// Search for player, working
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            view.RowFilter = "LastName like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
            if (textBox1.Text == "") view.RowFilter = string.Empty;
        }

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mattias\Dropbox\C#\Database\Baseball.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
        connection.Open();
        datatable.Load(new SqlCommand("select * from players", connection).ExecuteReader());
        dataGridView1.DataSource = view = datatable.DefaultView;
        connection.Close();
    }
```

// **Now working with CultureInfo**
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal minimum = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text);
            decimal maximum = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox3.Text);
// Should display players with different scores
            view.RowFilter = **String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat**,("BattingAverage >= {0} AND BattingAverage <= {1}"
                , minimum, maximum);

```
        if (textBox2.Text == "") view.RowFilter = string.Empty;
        if (textBox3.Text == "") view.RowFilter = string.Empty;
    }
```